# Fractional increment for enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am looking to create a numbered list such that the numbers of the list items be  incremented by fractional amounts as in  1.1, 1.2, 1.3... etc.

Can this be done by manipulating the `enumerate` counter?

Comment: [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package allows for this and many more options.

Comment: How should the numbering be when using two separated `enumerate` environments?

Comment: Possibly a pedantic nit-pick to some, but I'll make the following point anyway: I don't think what you're trying to achieve is "fractional numbering" of list items. Instead, I believe it should be called something like a "two-level" or "subordinated" numbering of list items. After all, if you have ten items under point "1", the tenth item is going to be numbered "1.10" rather than "2.0", right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on the usage, [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows to specify a `label` (and `ref`) option to `enumerate`. Here is a minimal example that steps some counter (`mycount`) at the start of every `enumerate`, and prints that counter in "fractional amounts":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newcounter{mycount} \renewcommand{\themycount}{\arabic{mycount}}%
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\stepcounter{mycount}}% Increment mycount at \begin{enumerate}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\themycount.\arabic*,ref=\themycount.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \item Another item
  \item Yet another item
\end{enumerate}
Here is some more text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \item Another item
  \item Yet another item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the means to "tap into" the start of `enumerate` and update the `mycount` counter and every instance.

`label` refers to how the enumeration label will be typeset, while `ref` refers to how it will be referenced from within the document (if you're using `\label` and `\ref`). The settings for `enumerate` are made global (via `\setlist[enumerate]{...}`), although it could also be localized to a particular `enumerate` environment via an option argument:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=.., ...]
```

If you're interested in labelling lists via some other counter (like `section`, or `subsection`, for instance), this is easily modifiable.

Comment: do you need `\refstepcounter` or are you ok without it?

Comment: @cmhughes: No, `\refstepcounter` is not needed, since `enumitem` ensures correct referencing via the `ref` label. If one had used `\refstepcounter`, then you could label the entire list by issuing `\label{<lab>}` even before the first `\item`. However, this wasn't requested or seemed necessary. `\refstepcounter` would not hurt, I agree...

Answer (score 5):

Here's another possible solution, which may appeal to people who like to use LaTeX's built-in functionality as much as possible.

I'm actually not perfectly sure if I've understood your question fully. Here's my interpretation of what you're looking for: you want to have separate first-level and second-level numbering systems, and the numbering of the second-level items should include the first level's counter as a "prefix". That way, if you have lots of second-level items, they'll get numbered as:

```
..., 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, ...
```

rather than as:

```
..., 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, ...
```

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii} % LaTeX's default: "(\theenumii)"
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{} % eliminate the default "prefix label", \theenumi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First first-level item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item A second-level item
  \item Another second-level item \label{enum:x}
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second first-level item \label{enum:y}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Here's a cross-reference to enumerated item \ref{enum:x},\\ 
and here's one to enumerated item \ref{enum:y}.
\end{document}
```

[image]